# Imprimir documento PDF diretamente via PHP ou JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, html, pdf

Gostaria de saber se há uma forma de imprimir um documento do tipo PDF diretamente(sem a necessidade de pressionar ctrl+p no browser) via PHP ou JavaScript. Por exemplo: criar um botão que, ao ser clicado, envia o documento PDF à fila de impressão do usuário. Sou iniciante nessas duas linguagens, por isso não sei se é uma dúvida de simples solução.

Comment: Eu achei isso, não sei se ajuda: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19124808/printing-pdfs-from-windows-command-line?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Basta utilizar o evento `window.print()`, por exemplo `<button type="button" onclick="window.print()">Imprimir</button>`. Para escolher os elementos que serão impressos, você pode utilizar um CSS específico para impressão.

Comment: Você pode, por exemplo, no PHP, chamar o PDFToPrinter da seguinte forma: `system('PDFToPrinter.exe ' . $pdfpath, $result);`, sendo que o PDFToPrinter está no link acima e, mais facilmente, neste aqui: http://www.columbia.edu/~em36/pdftoprinter.html

Comment: Deu certinho @MarceloUchimura, muito obrigado!!

Comment: Não é possível imprimir diretamente, o comando `system()` provavelmente só funcionou porque você está rodando em localhost, logo o servidor PHP está na mesma máquina que o navegador que abriu o endereço. Quando publicar em um servidor, isso se for WindowsServer, a impressão não será solicitada para computador do usuário, mas sim para o servidor, e logo o servidor pode estar do outro lado do mundo, isso se tiver impressora lá (provavelmente não tem, a maioria dos servers são "VPS")...

Comment: ... Não é possível imprimir diretamente pois se fosse possível poderia ser usado de forma errada pelos sites, como um "ataque" a máquina do usuário, usando a impressora dele indevidamente, por isso que para o `window.print()` é exigido a confirmação, para que o usuário final decida quando vai imprimir.